# Need some assistance in fixing the PowerShell formatting the Column export result to remove the SMTP: & smtp:?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server, scripting-language

I want to use the Replace string operation to make sure the result does not contain the **SMTP**: and **smtp**: string.

The below script export the list of the Disabled AD account with their corresponding Exchange mailbox details:

```
$filter = '(Enabled -eq $false) -and (homeMDB -ne "$null")'
$properties = @('homeMDB', 'mailNickName', 'mail', 'DisplayName', 'SamAccountName', 'ProxyAddresses')

$Allusers = (Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties  |
             ForEach-Object {

                $MBSize = (Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
                $MBLastLogonTime = (Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName).LastLogonTime
                $MBLastLoggedOnUserAccount = ((Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName).LastLoggedOnUserAccount)
                $MBDisconnectDate = ((Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName).DisconnectDate)
                $MBSMTPAddresses = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -like "*smtp:*" }).replace("smtp:","") -join ';'

                New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    DisplayName    = $_.DisplayName
                    mailNickName   = $_.mailNickName
                    SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
                    mail           = $_.mail
                    ProxyAddresses = $MBSMTPAddresses
                    homeMDB        = (($_.homeMDB).split(',')[0]).split('=')[1]
                    MBytes         = $MBSize
                    LastLogonTime  = $MBLastLogonTime
                    LastLoggedOnUserAccount = $MBLastLoggedOnUserAccount
                    DisconnectDate = $MBDisconnectDate
                }
            }) | Sort-Object MBytes -Descending | Export-Csv "C:\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem with the Export.CSV **ProxyAddresses** column output is the content of the column is like:

> SMTP:First.Last@domain.com;First.Last@domain2.com;Alias1@domain.com

Notice the **SMTP:email.user@domain.com** is still in the ProxyAddresses column in the Result.CSV all the lowercase ones are not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using class method `.Replace()` it **is case sensitive**. So you must change condition of `.Replace('smtp:','')` to upper case `.Replace('SMTP:','')` or use Powershell's `-replace` operator, which **is not case sensitive**.

```
$MBSMTPAddresses = (($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -like "*smtp:*" }) -replace 'smtp:') -join ';'
```

Comment: Yes, that works great, many thanks Kirill for your assistance.